# Run text query using Elasticsearch Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, solr

I'm working on a task wherein I have to replace Solr with Elasticsearch in a Java codebase. One method allows text queries to be submitted to Solr:

```
public List<String> executeQueryForCollection(SolrQuery query, String collectionName)
        throws IOException, SolrServerException {
    QueryResponse response = this.client.query(collectionName, query);
    return response.getResults();
}
```

Where `query` is any valid Solr query (`name_s:'Joe Bloggs' AND age_i:15`). What is the Elasticsearch equivalent to this (version 2.4.4)? Elasticsearch's [API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/2.4/java-search.html) seems much more restrictive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use a `query_string` query for this.

```
QueryStringQueryBuilder qs = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("name_s:'Joe Bloggs' AND age_i:15");
client.prepareSearch(index).setQuery(qs);
```

Comment: Is `client.prepareSearch(index).setQuery(qs)` preferable to `client.prepareSearch(index).setQuery("name_s:'Joe Bloggs' AND age_i:15")` or do they both do the same thing?

Comment: See my updated answer, `setQuery()` does not take strings, only query builder objects

Comment: OK thanks. `setQuery()` does take Strings in 2.4.4, but maybe `QueryBuilder` is safer in the long run.

Comment: You're right, I was checking the master branch ;-) So if you ever need to upgrade to ES 5.x if you use `setQuery(String)`, you'll have to refactor again.